# How to use call_user_func for static class method?

Tags: php, reflection, callback

The following code works fine.

```
LibraryTests::TestGetServer();
```

Get the array of functions in LibraryTests and run them:

```
$methods = get_class_methods('LibraryTests');
foreach ($methods as $method) {
  call_user_func('LibraryTests::' . $method . '()' );
}
```

This throws an error: `Warning: call_user_func(LibraryTests::TestGetServer()) [function.call-user-func]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback`

Here is the class that is being called:

```
class LibraryTests extends TestUnit {

    function TestGetServer() {
        TestUnit::AssertEqual(GetServer(), "localhost/");
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

How to fix?

Working in PHP 5.2.8.

Comment: Do not append `()` if the function has no parameters

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Either (as of PHP 5.2.3):

```
$methods = get_class_methods('LibraryTests');
foreach ($methods as $method) {
  call_user_func('LibraryTests::' . $method);
}
```

Or (earlier):

```
$methods = get_class_methods('LibraryTests');
foreach ($methods as $method) {
  call_user_func(array('LibraryTests', $method));
}
```

See [`call_user_func`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/call_user_func) and the [Callback Pseudo-Type<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).

Comment: Well you need to have a valid callback for that to work. If you put invalid values into `$method`, it does not work. If you put valid values in there, it does work. Take care that this is for static class methods only.

Comment: Both throw `... [function.call-user-func]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback in ...`

Comment: Well, first of all define the mehtod as static in your class: `static function TestGetServer` - or work on a class instance with the array notation. I linked two pages from the manual which contain a lot of information and examples and should lead you the way so that you can solve the problem in whichever way suits your needs.

Comment: OK, that worked. It needs `static` before `function TestGetServer()` in `class LibraryTests`. Thanks.