# php and call_user_function

Tags: php, function

If I have a set of functions

```
private function create() { echo "create...."; }
private function read() { echo "read...."; }
private function edit() { echo "edit...."; }
..
```

And how to use

```
if(is_callable($this,"create")) {
    call_user_func(array($this, "createe"), 'Hello World');
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Also if I have a set of static functions

```
private static function create() { echo "create...."; }
private static function read() { echo "read...."; }
private static function edit() { echo "edit...."; }
..
```

How to use this variant?

```
if(functon_exists("self::create")) {
    call_user_func(array($this, "createe"), 'Hello World');
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651250/how-to-use-call-user-func-for-static-class-method

Answer (score 0):

For the static function, use:

```
call_user_func(array('NameOfClass', 'create'));
```

or

```
call_user_func(array(get_class(), 'create'));
```

Comment: Or `call_user_func('NameOfClass::create');`